# In C position of ++ in regards to pointers

Tags: c, pointers

So My code runs differently when I have:
*ptr++;
and
++*ptr

I know the part about the ++ being in front you add first and when its in the back you add at the end. But this pointer increment is at the end of a method.
To clarify I'm just trying to move the pointer to the next character. This is a character type pointer.

Comment: What's the question? You write different code and your program works differently? That's not a question...

Comment: I just wanna know whats happening differently to this pointer

Comment: Take a look at [the operator precedence in C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). That will help.

Comment: As a thought exercise, try adding parentheses to show the order in which the * and ++ operations are done. That should show you why the two lines don't behave the same way. (Look up "precedence" if you don't know what order they are done...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*ptr++` is processed as `*(ptr++)`; it increments `ptr` but returns the original value, which is then dereferenced.

`++*ptr` is processed as `++(*ptr)` which dereferences the pointer, then increments the *value it points to* (*not* the pointer).

To preincrement the pointer, then get the value at the incremented location, you want `*++ptr`, which increments the pointer, then dereferences at the new location.

Comment: I'm personally against using this sort of nomenclature:  `*ptr++`.    Put the two operations on separate lines so the order is clear to anybody as is the intent.  The compiler will be smart enough to do the right thing and optimize it.

Comment: For C++ iterators, that's actually the better way to do it (because postfix increment on complex types involves copy constructors that prefix increment avoids). I'm generally in favor of avoiding pointer arithmetic (I've found the compilers are getting smart enough that indexing sometimes goes faster because it gives the compiler semantic information to work with that pointer arithmentic does not), but knowing how it works is a good thing since you will occasionally run into it (in canonical descriptions of `strcpy` if nothing else).

Answer (score -2):

`*ptr++` can be thought of as `*(ptr++)` it increments the address space then visits the value stored in the address space

Comment: So this would be what its doing?
*ptr contains 1
(*ptr)++ => 2?

Comment: `x = *ptr++;` is equivalent to `x = *ptr; ptr++;` whereas `(*ptr)++` is equivalent to `x = *ptr; x++; *ptr = x;`